# Can we configure a DNS Server and AD in two different physical machine to be accessible from a host?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

As i am somehow aware that AD itself needs to be DNS server to work. The real concern is that my company has a live DNS server working effectively. But now my management decided to control all the branches with proper AD.

Now i must migrate all the DNS entries to the AD configured server so that all the branches get access for all application as it was from previous DNS servers.
I had configured the DNS server in linux and everything is still there we have not migrated yet.

Is it possible if i use DNS server from existing server and configure only AD in new server so that client PC uses 2 different IP in their host one for DNS server and other one for AD access.

I did this but everytime if i need to be in AD i must assign IP address of AD in primary DNS server and if i need to access all the domains and subdomains of application and resources i must switch it's IP address again back to the primary DNS server. Assigning in  Alternative DNS Server do not works for both.

So, is it possible to do so with different DNS server and AD so that client PC can get access for both AD and DNS server configured in two different physical machines???????

Comment: Are the DNS zones in AD and in Linux the same zones?

Comment: If the zones contained within the linux server do not contain a zone with the same name as the active directory domain then yes.

Answer (score 1):

For correct functioning of AD it is *essential* that the domain controllers publish all the relevant AD records to at least one accessible DNS server. Most people try to set up more than one DNS server for redundancy. It is *essential* that all these servers return the same records. Do **not** be tempted to use a primary and secondary DNS servers that return different results.

A domain controller does not need to be a DNS server, this is an optional part of the `dcpromo` process. Nor do you have to use Microsoft DNS as long as your non-Microsoft DNS server complies with certain rules. See [this TechTarget Network article](https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-use-non-Microsoft-DNS-for-AD) for some tips. However, unless you have some really compelling reasons, life will be a lot simpler if you do use Microsoft DNS installed on some of your domain controllers.

It should be a trivial matter to import all your existing DNS records for any number of zones into the Microsoft DNS server. Here is a [helpful article from NT Weekly](https://www.ntweekly.com/2017/09/01/powershell-code-add-multiple-dns-records-csv-file-dns-server-using-powershell/).